# Shell script exit too early due to docker pull, while running through ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, bash, docker, shell

I have the following problem which seems to be caused by the "docker pull" in my shell script, as the pull works concurrently

```
#!/bin/bash   
#VARIABLES
    NAME="my-app"
    IMAGE="my-image:latest"
#DOCKER
    docker stop $NAME
    docker rm $NAME
    docker pull -q $IMAGE
    docker run --name $NAME -d -p 1234:8080 --log-opt fluentd-address=localhost:2233 $IMAGE
```

Running the script through the terminal works just fine everything works as expected. But when I run it with the Java's ProcessBuilder the script exits much quicker and it seems that it skips the "docker pull" step. As i am not a Java developer and I am not very well familiar with the Language I have the feeling that is something related to the multi-concurrent nature of the docker pull command and the way how the Java Process Builder executes the shell script

The Java class that runs the shell script is this

```
try {

    Collection<Task> tasks = taskService.getProjectTasksByProjectKey(projectId);

    Task findTask = findTaskByTaskId(tasks, taskId);
    if (findTask.getTaskId() != null) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(findTask.getCmdPath());
        Process process = pb.start();

        String output;

        try (InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
             InputStream err = process.getErrorStream();
             OutputStream closeOnly = process.getOutputStream()) {
            while (process.isAlive()) {
                long skipped = in.skip(in.available())
                        + err.skip(err.available());
                if(skipped == 0L) {
                    process.waitFor(5L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }
            }
            output = loadStream(in);
        } finally {
            process.destroy();
        }

//                String error  = loadStream(process.getErrorStream());
//                int rc = process.waitFor();

//                log.debug("exit code ->>> " + rc);
//                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
//                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
//                        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
//
//                String line;
//
//                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//                    output.append(line + "\n");
//                }
//
//                int exitVal = process.waitFor();
//                if (exitVal == 0) {
//                    System.out.println(output);
//
//                    return output.toString();
//                } else {
//                    //abnormal...
//                }

        return output;
    }
    else {
        throw new InvalidTaskModelException(taskId);
    }
} catch (InvalidModelException e) {
    throw new InvalidModelException(projectId);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return null;
}

private static String loadStream(InputStream s) throws Exception
{
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line=br.readLine()) != null)
    sb.append(line).append("\n");
return sb.toString();
}
```

The commented lines are different ways I tried to do it.

If anyone encountered a similar problem any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any exceptions anywhere?

Comment: Nope the script exits with 0 - When I log the code returned from "process.waitFor()" meaning everything went well.

Comment: What is the combined output from the commands actually run in the shell script?

Comment: my-app
my-app
my-app:latest
2b04e95049b020378b002229c91838b1f3e132af96aec1d5b7efce8ebd7111c6

The same happens when i run it through the ProcessBuilder but it does not pull the latest image from the Docker Hub, Basically what it does is to Stop the app, then re-run it but it runs it with the old image the new image was never downloaded. And this is the reason I don't understand for me is related to somehow to the Multi-download that docker CLI does when the Pull command is executed. Not sure how to explain it

Comment: @AtanasKovachev I've tested your java program without problems ( `IMAGE="nginx:alpine" )  as @Hiran Chaudhuri correctly states in his answer, the java code in the question can't correctly report the output since it skips the InputStream; but this way I see a correct output:
``` 
                while (process.isAlive()) {
                        process.waitFor(5L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }
```

Comment: You can put `exec > /tmp/log.txt 2>&1` as the second line in the script to log any errors to file instead of discarding them. This isn't running in some Windows compatibility layer, right?

Comment: I will try those solutions its a good idea to pipe the output to a log file and monitor what it does when I run it through the Java ProcessBuilder. It's also a good idea to try with docker rmi. Thank you will write later did it work

Comment: `Error response from daemon: pull access denied for myrepo/myApp, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied`. Checking the `log from exec > log.txt 2>&1` Is outputting the error above which probably makes sense. Cause when I run that command from the JVM the docker is not authenticated and it cannot pull the image as its a private repo. I feel so lame. I was testing with a free to pull repos it was working fine but before redirecting the output to a log file i was unaware of that log in issue

Answer (score 3):

It is good that you already take care for the processes' STDOUT and STDIN. But rather than skipping copy them to System.out so you can see what is going on. I suspect something is not going as per your expectations.

Looking at the bash script you posted and the fact you are trying to run several processes: Is it possible your java code is running the bash script line by line? Be aware your java program it is not a BASH interpreter, so e.g. variable substitution should not work.

Comment: The Variable Substitution works fine but you're right that the ProcessBuilder does not behave the same as the BASH interpreter. It turns out that when i run it through the PB docker fails to pull because the repo is private and it's saying that I need to log in. I was missing that as in my deployed version of the app i was reading the stderr but didn't append it to my output string. But one of the suggestion above was to use `exec > /tmp/log.txt 2>&1` which turns out to be what I needed to understand why it works from the bash terminal but not in PB. Thanks for your hep!

Answer (score 0):

why you can not run each command in thread and joins them so that unless therad 1 is not completed . next thread can not start .

also please add command to verify image is downloaded successfully

```
docker pull -q $IMAGE
docker images | grep $IMAGE
docker run --name $NAME -d -p 1234:8080 --log-opt fluentd-address=localhost:2233 $IMAGE
```

i am guessing there are 2 possiblities are here

1. Check local directory persmission if possible give 755 permission to
   it .
2. Java process itself is not able to execute docker command due
   to permission issue, run process as sudo user.